# Read a specific table column with Prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I need to read all the values of the first column of an HTML table, and I don't want to use DOM methods. I'd like a simpler solution using Prototype or YUI.

Note: the table is generated by a grid widget provided by an external team. That's why we cannot be sure of which IDs or Classnames are used.

In short I'd like something like:

```
For each row in table XXX
   value = row.column[1].value
   do something with value ...
End For
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what does the gride widget's code which generates the table look like?  or what does the generated table look like?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do something like $$('tr td:first-child') which should get the first td from each tr. You should then be able to use .innerHTML to get the value.

Comment: You could also write : $$('tr td:nth-child(1)'). Usefull if you want to select an other row than the first one.
As from prototype 1.5.1 any CSS3 selector should work http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#selectors

Answer (score 1):

possibly `$$('tr')` might work.  It returns an [array of elements based on a CSS rule](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/utility/dollar-dollar).

Answer (score 1):

Using Prototype

```
$('thetable').childElements()[0].childElements().invoke('firstDescendant');
```

It all cascades. The first one $('thetable') gets the table. I know you wanted minimal DOM but obviously you'll need to identify the table.

The second one gets all the childElements as an array and grabs the first one which is a tbody item.

Next it grabs of those elements' children which provides an array of table rows.

The last one calls invoke() calls a function on each element in that array. In this case, firstDescendant.

Answer (score 0):

this will get you an array of all the text values in the first column

```
var arr = $$('tr:first-child').pluck('innerText');
```

[pluck](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/enumerable/pluck)

[$$](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/utility/dollar-dollar)