# How do object or method chaining work in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frameworks

I am not asking what is the appropriate syntax for chaining, I know it could be something like:

```
$('myDiv').removeClass('off').addClass('on');
```

As far as I know chaining is one of the advantages against other famous frameworks. Can someone explain to me how chaining works here?

Comment: None of the answers below are complete, please check the documentation on `.end()`: http://api.jquery.com/end/, as jQuery not only returns the object a function is operating on, but if the selector is changed mid-chain, it retains the history of the selectors used as well so that you can "go back" to a previous selector used.

Comment: Here's the design pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

Comment: @Vibhu: OP wants to know how chaining works, not all the details of jQuery's implementation. *"...for a novice programer like me, I'm sure there is someone out there that can provide me with a explanation that allows me to understand how chaining works."*

Comment: Got very good answers! thanks to everyone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does basic object/function chaining work in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1099628/1048572)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If you have an object with certain methods, if each method returns an object with methods, you can simply call a method from the object returned.

```
var obj = {   // every method returns obj---------v
    first: function() { alert('first');   return obj; },
    second: function() { alert('second'); return obj; },
    third: function() { alert('third');   return obj; }
}

obj.first().second().third();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/5kkCh/

Comment: Instead of `return obj`, can you say `return this`? Because I tested and it gives me the same result.

Comment: @Derek: You could do that, because `this` in the functions in the example will be the object each method was called on.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I think that for people who are new-er to JavaScript the @squint answer's way of doing it (returning a reference to a variable instead of `this`) is clearer because `var that = this` seems to turn people off in my experience to wanting to learn programming, and they think it's hard. But I think your suggestion is clearer because it makes it more obvious how you might go about implementing multiple "depths" of chains

Comment: how accessing like array works, `$('a')[0]` gives first element

Comment: Since those functions contain 'obj' in their closure scope, doesn't this create a circular reference? Returning 'this' avoids that problem, so it's probably what you should do.

Answer (score 28):

All that it is doing is returning a reference to `this` when the method finishes. Take this simple object for example:

```
 var sampleObj = function()
 {
 };

 sampleObj.prototype.Foo = function()
 {
     return this;
 };
```

You could chain these calls all day because you return a reference to `this`:

```
var obj = new sampleObj();
obj.Foo().Foo().Foo().Foo() // and so on
```

jQuery simply performs an operation, then returns `this`.

Answer (score 8):

Basically the first function call `$('myDiv')` returns a jQuery object, then each subsequent call returns the same one.

Loosely,

```
var $ = function(selector) {
   return new jQuery(selector);
};

jQuery.prototype.removeClass = function(className) {
   // magic
   return this;
}
```

Comment: i find this explains how it works more than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
return $this;
```

each jQuery function returns an instance of the jQuery class, which can then have methods called on it. you could break it down, and this code would have the same effect.

```
jQuery_obj = $('myDiv');
jQuery_obj = jQuery_obj.removeClass('off');
jQuery_obj = jQuery_obj.addClass('on');
```

Answer (score 4):

The point is that a function must evaluate to the "parent" function. So e.g.

```
foo().bar().test();
```

has to evaluate to:

```
foo().test();
```

so that you can call another function on `foo()`. To do this, you can `return this`:

```
function foo() {
    // empty, nothing interesting here
}

foo.prototype.bar = function() {
    return this;
}

foo.prototype.test = function() {
    return this;
}
```

Then,

```
var something = new foo();
something.bar() === something; // true
```

And because of this:

```
something.bar().test() === something.test(); // true
```

So because `something.bar()` evaluates to `something`, you can immediately call the second function in one go.

Answer (score 4):

In chaining parent function/method returns an object which is then used by the child function/method, and things go on such a way. In short the `jQuery` or `$` returns itself (an object) which allows the chaining.

It is the same mechanism below

```
var obj=$('input');    //returns jQuery object
var obj1=obj.val('a'); //returns jQuery object
var obj2=obj1.fadeOut();//returns jQuery object
```

It looks like this if it is done with chaining

```
$('input').val('a').fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of conditional callback chaining, like is used on the `$.ajax` jQuery function.

```
// conditional callback function example
myFunction = function () {

    // define event callback prototypes without function parameter
    var callback_f = new Object;
    callback_f.callback1 = function () { return callback_f; };
    callback_f.callback2 = function () { return callback_f; };

    if ([condition]){
        // redefine the callback with function parameter 
        // so it will run the user code passed in
        callback_f.ReturnPlayer = function (f) { f(); return callback_f; };
    }else{ 
        callback_f.NewPlayer = function (f) { f(); return callback_f; };
    }

    return callback_f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to chaining, check [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ybbnoow3/) .

```
test("element").f1().f2().f3()
```

Answer (score 0):

> Chaining is used to connect multiple events and functions in a selector.
>
> To run multiple jQuery commands, one after the other, on the same element(s). Generally chaining uses the jQuery built in functions that makes compilation a bit faster.
>
> It makes your code short and easy to manage and it gives better performance,

**Eaxample**

> Without Chaining

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dvContent').addClass('dummy');
    $('#dvContent').css('color', 'red');
    $('#dvContent').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

> With Chaining

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dvContent').addClass('dummy')
          .css('color', 'red')
          .fadeIn('slow');     
});
```

> **Note:** The chain starts from left to right. So left most will be called first and so on.

Answer (score 0):

[Chaining](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp) allows us to run multiple jQuery methods (on the same element) within a single statement.

The following example chains together the `css()`, `slideUp()`, and `slideDown()` methods. The "p1" element first changes to red, then it slides up, and then it slides down :

```
 $("#p1").css("color", "red").slideUp(2000).slideDown(2000);
```

Comment: The OP didn't ask what chaining is; they asked how chaining works. The [answer from user113716](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7475375/597460) explains it.