# access an extended object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, instantiation

I am having a bit of trouble creating an instance of useful things 
from another JS file, I would like to change the properties of the 
instance and use the methods. Or whatever you suggest if this is not 
possible. This extends and this construct are confusing me.

```
(function($) {

$.extend({
    usefulThings: new function() {
        this.defaults = {
            prop_path:'/la/lala',
            //OTHER STUFF
        };
        this.construct = function(options) {
            return this.each(function() {
                var setting;
                this.settings = {};
                settings = $.extend(this.settings, $.usefulThings.defaults, options);
                $this = $(this);

                //OTHER STUFF
                $.data(this, "usefulThings",settings);
                // FIRST METHOD CALL
                //OTHER STUFF
            });
        };
        //SOME METHODS
    }
});
$.fn.extend({
    usefulThings: $.usefulThings.construct
}); 
})(jQuery);
```

I have seen usefulThings called from script blocks like so:

```
$("#myDivName").usefulThings({
  prop_path: '/la/lala' //these seems to get overwritten in the above
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, have a look at [MDN's introduction to the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). And in the jQuery docs for [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Next, check out [how does jquery chaining work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7475336/1048572) to understand the construct method.

Then, you should notice that the use of the `new` keyword is absolutely inappropriate in this case. The expression should be replaced by a simple object literal:

```
{
    defaults: {
        prop_path:'/la/lala',
        // …
    },
    construct: function(options) {
        …
    },
    //SOME METHODS
}
```

Now, the [`jQuery.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/). The relevant sentence from the docs is

> If only one argument is supplied to `$.extend()`, this means the `target` argument was omitted. In this case, the `jQuery` object itself is assumed to be the target. By doing this, you can add new functions to the `jQuery` namespace. This can be useful for plugin authors wishing to add new methods to JQuery.

And it's the same for `$.fn.extend` (which actually is `=== $.extend`), it extends the `jQuery.fn` object which is a shortcut for jQuery's prototype object.

Comment: I looked into all the stuff you wrote and it was pretty informative. I learned a few things. Ultimately, my problem was the file containing usefulThings hadn't loaded yet when I tried to call it.  I wrapped it in window.onload = function() {$("#myDivName").usefulThings({prop_path: '/la/lala'});} and it worked. I feel like someone just told me to clear my cache. feelin' real rookie right now.