# find img element and replace with something using js

Tags: javascript, jquery

My source is generated with obvious error in setting align and margin attribute at img element. So my html src is

```
<p><img left margin: 5px;" src="http://techtools4biz.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/Google-logo-300x242-150x150.jpg" alt="" /></p>
```

ofcourse it should be `<img align="left" margin=".." src="..." />`

In my previous question someone recommended to use find left element which and to replace him with align left property like this

```
$('img'.attr("left")){
    $(this).removeAttr('left');
    $(this).attr("align","left");
};
```

Tried and it doesn't work, any suggestions?

here's the link 
http://jsfiddle.net/GJRmB/

Comment: Simply this should work for you: $('img').attr("align","left"); you don't need to do this and then remove or add attributes

Comment: Don't try and fix broken code on the client (a browser will try and, *unpredictably*, salvage the HTML when constructing the DOM, which happens before jQuery's `$(document).ready()` event-handling); fix the source of the problem (whatever it is that's generating this broken HTML).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is guaranteed that the pattern will be always like that, you can use Regex. Actually you should fix whatever generates the source to start with... but lets go...

[Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GJRmB/1/)

```
// the image is wrapped in `p`, so we can easily grab its generated HTML code
var imgMessedHtml = $("img").parent().html();

// now assuming that pattern is always like that, we can try extracting the
// attributes
var align = imgMessedHtml.match(/img (\w+)/i)[1];
var margin = imgMessedHtml.match(/margin.*?(\d+px)/i)[1];
```

After we get the information we need, we can fix the source

```
// I am removing everything between `img` and `src`
$("img").parent().html(
    imgMessedHtml.replace(/img.*?src/i, "img src")
);
```

Now with the data we extracted we can set it to the `img`

```
$("img").attr("align", align);
$("img").attr("margin", margin);
```

[Regex is really not recommended to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/340760), but if you have no other choice then...

Comment: since regex is so cryptic to me I have to ask you what if I want to replace <img left; ../> with <img align="left" /> just one more semicolon after left in my question code

Answer (score 1):

You are mismatching the brackets

```
var $img = $('img');
$img.removeAttr('left');
$img.attr("align","left");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Sza99/)

or use chaining

```
jQuery(function(){
    var $img = $('img').removeAttr('left').attr("align","left");
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mHawf/)

Comment: I think he was trying to replace an existing "left" attribute with `align="left"`. It's not in his fiddle but it's in his code..

Comment: You've noted that there is no `left` attribute in the linked demo (not that this breaks the jQuery, but it seems to render the question moot)?

Comment: @DavidThomas it looks fine after updating the OP's markup also http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mHawf/2/

Comment: @Itay from what I understood the OP is trying to make the alignment properly using a jQuery script... which the fiddle seems to be doing

Answer (score 1):

You can use chaining and **[the attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)**:

```
$('img[left]').removeAttr('left').attr("align","left");
```

### [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/A4trQ/)

**See aslso:**

- [How does jquery chaining work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7475336/1935077)
- [*Has Attribute Selector `[name]`* in the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)