# How to add more to this jQuery statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$( '#mytable button' ).click( function( event ) {
```

id like to animate it.  so on `.click` it will do `.parents('tr').css('background-color', '#3c3c3c')`  and stay that color.

Possible?   I am new to jquery, still completing classes.  Sorry for the dumb question, but its easy points if someone gives me a helpful answer.  Maybe point me to a resource that explains how to structure the code when adding multiple actions.

How do I add more?  $( '#mytable button' ).click.css(here?)( function( event ) {

Comment: How do you want this animated? See this: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: (If you want to animate the color change, the docs recommend this plugin: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color)

Comment: I dont know where to add the extra code, thats the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this** http://jsfiddle.net/qNTda/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/qNTda/1/

Hope it fits your need man! Not sure what exactly you are aiming but this will give you good playing ground. lemme know if you need help.

API: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

By the way I reckon by "multiple action" you mean "chaining" read here if you keen: [how does jquery chaining work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475336/how-does-jquery-chaining-work) 
`:)`

**Code**

```
$('button').click(function () {
    alert($(this).parents().find('table#mytable').html());
    $(this).parents().find('table#mytable').animate({
        backgroundColor: '#3c3c3c'
    });
});
```