# Is jquery method chaining using callbacks internally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, method-chaining

I am assuming that jquery's method chaining has to do something with callbacks internally.

> A callback function is executed after the current effect is finished.

In the following jquery method chaining code, `slideUp(2000)` has to be completed in order for `slideDown(2000)` to be executed. Which means it is as same as the callback functions.

**with method chaining**

```
 $("#p")slideUp(2000).slideDown(2000);
```

**with callbacks**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").slideUp(2000, function(){
            $("p").slideDown(2000);
        });
    });
});
```

I am getting the same effect from both the codes. Does it mean that jquery method chaining is implemented using callbacks internally?

Comment: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=2.1.3&fn=jQuery.fn.slideUp

Comment: Check how jquery chaining works and no it does'nt use callbacks internally!!...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475336/how-does-jquery-chaining-work..

Comment: Why don't you take a look at its source code?