# Javascript JQuery chaining

Tags: javascript, jquery, chaining

Let's say we have :

```
$("p")[0].innerHTML;
```

and

```
$("p").html();
```

In the above examples, we have the same result. So I was wondering how can JQuery return both the nodelist and itself to allow chaining ?

Comment: It's because the jQuery selector returns an object. You're then just calling the properties of that object, in this case `html` and `0`. If you `console.log($('p'))` you'll see all the methods listed.

Comment: Do `console.log($("p"));` and `console.log($("p")[0]);` you will understand.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475336/how-does-jquery-chaining-work/7475375#7475375

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I was wondering how can JQuery return both the nodelist and itself to allow chaining ?

It doesn't.

It only returns itself (which it an object).

That object has a property called `0` which contains the first element in the array of elements. It also has a property called `html` which contains a function.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie — It [isn't an array](http://jsbin.com/fadonu/1/edit?js,console), but even if it was, so what? Arrays (except empty arrays) have a property called `0`. An array is just an object which inherits some properties along the prototype chain from `Array` and is designed to hold data using properties with integer values as their names.

Comment: Just checked and you are correct. That's cute. It implies that `$("p")["0"].innerHTML` also works which I just tested and yes, it has a number property for each "array" entry. Thanks for that little titbit. My ignorance has lessened +1 :)

Comment: It's less magical than what I was expecting. So if I've understood well, each element that is retrieved with the selector is stored as a property with a numeric index ?

Answer (score 0):

that is called fluent syntax. each function returns the object it is given. something like

```
function f(obj){
    doSomething(obj);
    return obj; 
}
```