# jQuery combining document.ready and ajaxComplete methods together for same code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Want to apply same code on page load and on ajax complete. Below is the code

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    showHideBlock();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    showHideBlock();
});

function showHideBlock() {
    if ($('.reservationDetails').length == 1) {
        $('.user-reservation-info').show();
    } else {
        $('.user-reservation-info').hide();
    }
}
```

Any other better way of doing it?

Comment: okay and what is the problem?

Comment: any other better way of doing it?

Comment: What is your expectation when you say _"better"_? Do you mean shorter?

Comment: yes some shorter way. I am not happy with my code. Feeling it can be better and shorter.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [method chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7475336/2950032) and shorten the code that attaches the handlers for `ready` and `ajaxComplete`. You could avoid typing `$('.user-reservation-info')` twice by storing it in a variable. Also, since your `if..else` code is pretty simple, you could use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```
$(document).ready(showHideBlock).ajaxComplete(showHideBlock);

function showHideBlock() {
    var userInfo = $('.user-reservation-info');
    $('.reservationDetails').length === 1 ? userInfo.show() : userInfo.hide();
}
```

You can also replace `$('.reservationDetails').length === 1` with just `$('.reservationDetails').length` in the above code, if you're just doing it to check if `.reservationDetails` matches any elements in the DOM. But, if you specifically need `length` to be 1, then this can't be done.

Comment: $(document).on('ajaxComplete ready', function() {
  if($('.reservationDetailsTitle').length) {
    $('.user-reservation-info').show();
  }else{
    $('.user-reservation-info').hide();
  }
})

I have used above and that worked! Anyways thanks for the answer :)