# Java StringBuilder append() return?

Tags: java, string, oop

I'm just new in Java programming and it's really confusing me that what's the return type of method append() in StringBuilder??

I've checked about the API documents on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/String.html and the return is "StringBuilder", so I should write the code like:

```
StringBuilder a=new StringBuilder("hello");
...(another StringBuilder object)=a.append("world");
```

and a will still be "hello", and another stringbuilder will become"helloworld" because it has a return value??

But actually a itself also become "helloworld". Why??Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: [**Fluent Interface**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#Java).

Comment: Also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is reasonable that `StringBuilder` follows the [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), as it is used for building a String.

In a builder pattern each method (mostly) returns the current instance so that the return is a modified instance.

> But actually a itself also become "helloworld". Why??

Because you are using the same instance to append again., so it already stored the previous value and was given the updated instance.

> so I should write the code like:
>
> StringBuilder a=new StringBuilder("hello");
>   ...(another StringBuilder object)=a.append("world");

You need not to. Since that returning the instance you can chain your method calls. That is the beauty of builder pattern.

```
StringBuilder a=new StringBuilder("hello");
a.append("World").append(" Mr.").append("Blah");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how should I know whether this method has this "builder pattern" or not?

Comment: As I said earlier, most of the methods from that class return the same type and methods have `return  this`

Comment: Here is an example implementation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern#Java

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 3):

## Why append returns a `StringBuilder`

So that you can append "a", "b" and "c" like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()
        .append("a")
        .append("b")
        .append("c");
```

## What is returned

The `StringBuilder` returned is the same as the one that was called on, so this:

```
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sb2 = sb1.append("a")
        .append("b")
        .append("c");
System.out.println(sb1 == sb2);
```

Prints out `true`, this is why the 2 `StringBuilder`s in your example had the same text, because they are the same `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 2):

This is in order to allow [chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining):

`sb.append("a").append("b").append("c"). ...`

Without this you would have to repeat sb: `sb.append("a"); sb.append("b"); ...`

This pattern is common in builders and most famous with [jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475336/how-does-jquery-chaining-work).
In general this can be useful, but when the chain becomes hard to read it can also introduce bugs.

Answer (score 2):

The `StringBuilder` class (as well as its thread-safe sibling, `StringBuffer`) offers a [fluent builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#Java) pattern.

Most methods return the modified instance of your `StringBuilder` after applying the method, so you can chain-invoke methods on it.

You an either invoke `append` as you would a `void` returning method, and disregard the returned `StringBuilder` for one shot operations, or you can chain invocations, in the safety that you're still manipulating the same `StringBuilder` step by step.

**Example**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("a"); // void-like invocation
sb.append("b").append("c"); // chained invocation
// terminal invocation as it doesn't return an instance of 
// StringBuilder, but (immutable) String
String s = sb.toString(); // "abc"
```

Answer (score 0):

StringBuilder actually returns *this* ( current object) in append method of it.