# How to Define a function to invoke like this: function1().function2()?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
 function1().function2();
```

How to Define a function to invoke like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how does jquery chaining work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475336/how-does-jquery-chaining-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here you have a working example, you can call `function1` and get the object mapping to the functions that you desire.

```js
function function1() {
  return {
    function2: f2
  }
}

function f2() {
  return "do something";
}

console.log(function1().function2())
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the other answers, you usually would do this when coding a fluent interface, where you are returning the parent object to allow method chaining, which you could do like so:

```js
var calculator = (function() {
      var i = 0;
      var public = {};
      public.add = function(a) { i += a; return public; }
      public.sub = function(a) { i -= a; return public; }
      public.equals = function() { return i; }
      return public;
})();
    
console.log(calculator.add(2).sub(3).add(20).equals());
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need `function1` to return an object that has a property of `function2`. For example:

```js
function f1() {
  return {
    f2() {
      console.log('foo');
    }
  };
}
f1().f2();
```

Comment: He was probably looking for function that would return parent object so he can do `fn1().fn2().fn1()...`

Comment: The question did not specify such, so I didn't assume anything.