# Multiple jquery functions in one line on a html element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html element on which I should do multiple things on if condition.
My present code:

```
<div>
  <label for="myInput">Add Number</label>
  <input id="myInput" type="number" required>
</div>

<script>
  if (someCondition) {
    $("#myInput").removeAttr("required");
    $("#myInput").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#myInput").val() = "";
  }
</script>
```

My question is, is it possible to condense the jquery code? If yes then how?

Comment: The term you're looking for is "chaining" or, specifically, [jquery chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475336/how-does-jquery-chaining-work).  Found a small note on it in learn.jquery.com: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/working-with-selections/#chaining

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it in a single line then you can do

```
$("#myInput").removeAttr("required").prop("disabled", true).val("");
```

Also `$("#myInput").val() = "";` is not valid, it should be `$("#myInput").val("");`

Also as Roko pointed out it should be `disabled` and not `diabled`

**Demo**

```js
if (true) {
  $("#myInput").removeAttr("required").prop("disabled", true).val("");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label for="myInput">Add Number</label>
  <input id="myInput" type="number" required value="2">
</div>
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan good one didnt event noticed that one :) Thanks

Comment: Thanks for pointing the typo. I will rectify it.