# How to create a function that will render items of a global variable into a pre-existing list in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a function that will render the toDo items as list items in the unorderedList

Create a function renderList that renders the todo items from toDos as list items in the unordered list, make sure that the function is dynamic and that it gets invoked at when while loading the page

How do yo do this in Jquery?

```
const body = $("body");
const header =$("<header>Todo List</header>")
const unorderedList = $("<ul>unorderedlist</ul>")
var toDos = ["wake up","eat breakfast","code"];

/*const renderList function()=>{
       
{
*/
body.append(header)
body.append(unorderedList)
body.append(toDos);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [*map*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) your array to a list of elements and [*append*](https://api.jquery.com/append/#append-content-content) them to the list

```js
const toDos = ["wake up", "eat breakfast", "code"];

$("<ul>") // create a <ul>
  .append(toDos.map(text => $("<li>", { text }))) // create <li> elements and append them
  .appendTo(document.body) // append the <ul> to <body>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

To explain this part...

```js
$("<li>", { text })

// or more verbosely
$("<li>", { text: text })

// or even more verbosely
$("<li>").text(text)
```

See https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes. It's creating a new `<li>` element and setting the `text` property to the current value in the `toDos` array.

---

For completeness, here's the [*you might not need jQuery*](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) version

```js
const createElement = (tag, props = {}) =>
  Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props)

const toDos = ["wake up", "eat breakfast", "code"];

const ul = createElement("ul")
ul.append(...toDos.map(textContent => createElement("li", { textContent })))

document.body.append(ul)
```

Comment: first of all thank you very much for the answer!
May I ask you:
 How does it know when you write  $("<ul>") which ul to choose, what if i had multiple <uls> in the code ?
How does this function start and finish, what if I wrote code below it, is the code a part of it ? or does it end after you append

Comment: When you use a full tag string (ie `"<ul>"` as opposed to `"ul"`), jQuery creates a new element for you. If you wanted to select a particular element that was already in the document, you would just use a selector like `$("#id-of-element")`

Comment: Also how do you read this part     (text => $("<li>", { text }) ?

sorry I am just trying to understand and I dont like to copy paste ^_^

Comment: @Adam.M I've updated my answer with an explanation of that part

Comment: Thank you Phil, you are amazing, I am loving Jquery by the minute, just hate that its very shortened to the point where its kinda hard to understand whats going on  when you see the 
code for the first time
And not to mention  iam use to  curly brackets which tells me hey, we started here we end here.
in jquery i dont see how i can know start and end unless i just start using space between code

Comment: @Adam.M I think you might be referring to jQuery's method chaining. Have a read of this post ~ [how does jquery chaining work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475336/how-does-jquery-chaining-work)

Comment: @Adam.M also, with modern browsers there's a very good chance [you might not need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/). I've added a vanilla JS version for comparison

Answer (score 0):

Not need *jQuery*.
**`Create`** elements and **`append`** them to the list with help of **`map()`** method.

```js
const header = document.createElement("header");
const txt = document.createTextNode("Todo List");
header.appendChild(txt);
document.body.appendChild(header);

const toDos = ["wake up", "eat breakfast", "code"];
const ul_List = document.createElement("ul");
toDos.map(function(val){
    const li_List = document.createElement("li");
    li_List.innerHTML = val;
    ul_List.appendChild(li_List)
});
document.body.appendChild(ul_List);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my homework is strict on using jquery as practice :) 
I took dom last week, i fully understand how its done with your answer via dom

Comment: @Adam.M :) So you can preferer https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_add.asp url for better understand of jQuery DOM.

Comment: You're misusing `map()` since you are not returning anything or using the result. `forEach()` would be a better fit