# Is there a way to make native function chainable?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does basic object/function chaining work in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099628/how-does-basic-object-function-chaining-work-in-javascript)

Is there a way to make native function chainable?

For example, I want to do this:

```
var ele = document
            .createElement("div")
            .setAttribute("id", "foo")
            .focus();
```

instead of this:

```
var ele = document.createElement("div");
ele.setAttribute("id", "foo");
ele.focus();
```

Is there a way to do that? If it is possible, then it will definitely save me a lot of typing works.