# Understanding difference between $.ajax() and $.ajax().then

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having trouble understanding the following code:

```
var x = $.ajax({
    url : "sample_url",
    dataType : "json",
    data : {
        "invalidate_cache" : true
    }
});
```

Now, if I do

```
var y = x.then();
```

It returns the same function as **x**. 
Also what would have been different if **x** had been assigned the following way (Apart from "Hello 1" getting printed during ajax success return):

```
var x = $.ajax({
    url : "sample_url",
    dataType : "json",
    data : {
        "invalidate_cache" : true
    }
}).then(function(data){console.log("Hello 1")};
```

Comment: `x` will always be promise returned by `$.ajax`. Promises can be chained using `then()`. Question is difficult to answer the way it is asked. Did you have different expectations for what `x` would be?

Comment: this is called chaining. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099628/how-does-basic-object-function-chaining-work-in-javascript

Comment: @charlietfl Yes. I expect different definitions for "x" when $.ajax() is assigned to it in comparison to $.ajax().then()
I want to know the concept behind such declarations.

Comment: @Hacketo Thanks. I will look into this concept

Comment: Probably better to figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: @charlietfl I am simply trying to assign an ajax promise to **x**. Later in the code, I will use x.then(function(y){ });

Comment: And is it not working? If not then showing problematic code would be best rather than an abstract question of what `x` is

Comment: @charlietfl No, the code works. But I didn't know about chaining. I was under the assumption that $ajax and $ajax.then have different reference values

Comment: They would resolve differently if you returned something from `then()`

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry, I meant reference to function definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `ajax` and `then` functions will return you a promise.  I don't want to explain the whole promise mechanism but to answer the question, the difference between the first and the second `x` is that the first one will be execute right after the `ajax` call resolve while the second one will resolve after the function specified as parameter in the `then` function is executed (Note that the `then` function will be executed after the `ajax` call resolves... this is called chaining).

Comment: So, both 'ajax' and 'then' function return the **same** promise?

Comment: No, they would be different instance.

Comment: Thanks. I looked up chaining and it cleared my doubts