# Pass result of functional chain to function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

If I have an array `someArray` that I first want to do some operations on and then pass that result to a function `arrfun` that takes an array as an argument. Like the following

```
let arr = someArray.filter(foo).map(bar)
let result = arrfun(arr)
```

In the above scenario I would like to avoid having to assign an intermediary variable to be passed to `arrfun`. I would like to have something like this.

```
Object.prototype.pipe = function(f) {return f(this)}

let result = someArray.filter(foo).map(bar).pipe(arrfun)
```

- In lieu of a `.pipe()` how would you solve this?
- Would it be sensible to introduce that function to `Object`?
- Is `pipe` the best name for such a function? `chain`? `pass`?

**New example**

```
const pc = options => options
  .join(' ')
  .match(/--[\w.]* [\w.]*/g)
  .map(s => s.slice(2).split(' '))
  .map(([key, value]) => ({key, value}))
  .map(nestObject)
  .reduce((acc, val) => Object.assign(acc, val), {})

const nestObject = ({key, value}) => key
  .split('.')
  .reverse()
  .reduce((inner, key) => ({[key]: inner}), value)
```

In the above example a problem is that `.match` returns `null` if no match is found. Using `.pipe` you could solve it ny changing that line to

```
.pipe(s => s.match(/--[\w.]* [\w.]*/g) || [])
```

How would you solve this one without `pipe`?

Comment: What's wrong with just `arrfun(someArray.filter(foo).map(bar))`?

Comment: If you really want to introduce a new method on `Object.prototype`, [do it properly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13296340/1048572) at least (but no, [it's not sensible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180/1048572)).

Comment: [`chain`](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#chain) means something different

Comment: What's wrong with just `(options.join(…).match(…) || []).map(…).…`?

Comment: Because, in my opinion, wrapping stuff like that doesn't scale in terms of readability. I think that already in this example the stuff that gets wrapped is to large and imagine having more wrappers. Just chaining stuff is much more simple.

Comment: One could also say that chaining stuff is *too* simple for complex use cases. There were good reasons for introducing variables and branching in JS syntax :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the above scenario I would like to avoid having to assign an intermediary variable to be passed to `arrfun`.

Are you overlooking this simple, straightforward expression ?

```
let result = arrfun(someArray.filter(foo).map(bar))
```

---

**right-to-left function composition**

Or maybe you wish for classic (right-to-left) function composition?

```js
const compose = (f,...fs) => x =>
  f === undefined ? x : f(compose(...fs)(x))

const filter = f => xs =>
  xs.filter(x => f(x))

const map = f => xs =>
  xs.map(x => f(x))

const foo = x =>
  x > 3
  
const bar = x =>
  x * x
  
const arrfun = xs =>
  xs.reverse()

const myfunc =
  compose(arrfun, map(bar), filter(foo))

let someArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

let result = myfunc(someArray)

console.log(result)
// [ 36, 25, 16 ]
```

---

**left-to-right function composition**

The same answer as above using left-to-right function composition

```js
const compose = (f,...fs) => x =>
  f === undefined ? x : compose(...fs)(f(x))

const filter = f => xs =>
  xs.filter(x => f(x))

const map = f => xs =>
  xs.map(x => f(x))

const foo = x =>
  x > 3
  
const bar = x =>
  x * x
  
const arrfun = xs =>
  xs.reverse()

// notice order of functions
const myfunc =
  compose(filter(foo), map(bar), arrfun)
  
let someArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

let result = myfunc(someArray)

console.log(result)
// [ 36, 25, 16 ]
```

---

**Identity functor**

> I dont think wrapping the entire thing scales in terms of readability. Imagine that you have to chain some more stuff to arrfun and then wrap that thing in yet another function.

You should see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44109078/633183) I wrote about the Identity functor - This gives you a chainable interface but doesn't touch native prototypes

```js
const Identity = x => ({
  runIdentity: x,
  map: f => Identity(f(x))
})

const foo = x =>
  x > 3
  
const bar = x =>
  x * x
  
const arrfun = xs =>
  xs.reverse()

const myfunc = xs =>
  Identity(xs)
    .map(xs => xs.filter(foo))
    .map(xs => xs.map(bar))
    .map(xs => arrfun(xs))
    .runIdentity

let someArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

let result = myfunc(someArray)

console.log(result)
// [ 35, 25, 16 ]
```

Of course if you keep `filter` and `map` as we defined before, it cleans up the definition of `myfunc`

```js
const Identity = x => ({
  runIdentity: x,
  map: f => Identity(f(x))
})

const filter = f => xs =>
  xs.filter(x => f(x))

const map = f => xs =>
  xs.map(x => f(x))

const foo = x =>
  x > 3
  
const bar = x =>
  x * x
  
const arrfun = xs =>
  xs.reverse()

const myfunc = x =>
  Identity(x)
    .map(filter(foo))
    .map(map(bar))
    .map(arrfun)
    .runIdentity

let someArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

let result = myfunc(someArray)

console.log(result)
// [ 35, 25, 16 ]
```

And don't get hung up on `foo` and `bar` being defined up front. We can use lambda expressions directly within `myfunc` if you wanted to

```
const myfunc = xs =>
  Identity(xs)
    .map(xs => xs.filter(x => x > 3))
    .map(xs => xs.map(x => x * x))
    .map(arrfun)
    // or skip defining arrfun somewhere else and just ...
    // .map(xs => xs.reverse())
    .runIdentity
```

Comment: I dont think wrapping the entire thing scales in terms of readability. Imagine that you have to chain some more stuff to arrfun and then wrap that thing in yet another function. I might have overlooked composition though. Only thing that might be a disadvantage might be that I have to define functions first and then compose (might be a good thing as well).

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. The **Identity functor** is nice for making a chainable interface without touching native prototypes. Let me know if I can help you any further ^_^

Comment: Regarding your comment edit, `foo` and `bar` do not need to be predefined - they can be lambda expressions written directly in `myfunc`

Comment: Very good examples, learned some nice stuff there, thnx. I added an extra example in the post that is a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

You could compose your manipulator function and your result function first as reusable functions. Like:

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
const manipulatorFn = arr => arr.map(item => item +1);
const arrFunc = (arr, fn) => fn(arr);
```

or if you want to do some more stuff in the arrFunc

```
const arrFunc = (arr, fn) => {
  let a = fn(arr);

  // do some more stuff with a
  return a;
};
```

now you can fetch your result

```
let result = arrFunc(arr, manipulatorFn);
```