# Best way to add null checker to querySelector in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have parsed xml
and I'm using querySelector

for example:

```
this.querySelector("TYPE").textContent
```

Sometimes value of `this.querySelector("TYPE")` is null so previous line returns an error.

What is the most beautiful way to avoid errors?

I'm doing it with something like the following:

```
example = this.querySelector("TYPE") != null ? this.querySelector("TYPE").textContent : "" //UGLY!
```

But it is too long and looks bad.

Other way:
Own function like `findInXml(this, "TYPE"),` but when I want to look deeper it's looks that:

```
findInXml(findInXml(this, "TYPE"), "STH") // UGLY!
```

I prefer to use it this way for example:

```
this.findXml("TYPE").findXml("STH") //Looks nice
```

Comment: I think the one-line conditional statement is fine

Comment: Maybe you want to see this: [function chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1099771/6320039)

Comment: You are right, but is it possible to check if previous obj is null with that?

Does it call function on null element? null.checkNull() to my mind won't work.

Comment: Calling `querySelector` twice in the one line conditional seems rather wasteful when you only need to call it once.

Answer (score 1):

One call to `querySelector`:

```
var typeEl;
var example = (typeEl = this.querySelector("TYPE")) ? typeEl.textContent : '';
```

JSPerf agrees:

https://jsperf.com/nullqueryselector/1

Comment: @Yas - your goal is not to write beautiful code, it's to write readable code. Readable code = beautiful code, if you haven't gotten to this point yet, you will. The niftiest one liners are absolute hell to discern at a glance.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional line statement like :

```
example = (this.querySelector("TYPE") && this.querySelector("TYPE").textContent) || '';
```

Comment: Pretty terrible because it calls querySelector twice unnecessarily.

Comment: you can use some variable or put code in function then 

example = ((type = document.querySelector("TYPE")) && type.textContent) || '';