# How to append methods in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with jQuery, making a WordPress website, and ran into issues because Wordpress doesn't seem to work with the `$(window).load(...)` event listener, due to which I had to change the code.

Here's the original code in jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function(){
...
}).resize(function() {
...
});
```

Hers's what I'd changed it to:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
...
}).resize(function() {
...
});
```

However, I get an error in console `TypeError: windowAddEventListener is undefined`. How can I solve this?

Comment: `$(function(){ $(window).on("resize",function() {....});  })`   should work

Comment: addEventListener doesn't return. You need to add another event listener

Comment: Vanilla Javascript has very limited method chaining - one of the strengths/benefits of using jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does basic object/function chaining work in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099628/how-does-basic-object-function-chaining-work-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. `addEventListener` return undefined so you can't do anything after it
2. in vanilla JavaScript there are no `resize` function this is only in jQuery.

You will need this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
...
});

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
...
});
```

and if you want chaining you will need:

```
const x = {
    load: function(fn) {
        window.addEventListener('load', fn);
        return this;
    },
    resize: function(fn) {
        window.addEventListener('resize', fn);
        return this;
    }
};

x.load(function() {

}).resize(function() {

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer; Just solved it---and many other issues---by replacing the `window.addEventListener` with `$(window).load`.