# Syntax of Promises in javascript is confusing

Tags: javascript, promise

To access a method of the object we use dot operator like `nameOfObject.nameOfMethod()`. This is how I understand the dot operator.

This understanding of the dot operator is not helping me understand the syntax of promises in JavaScript.  E.g see the code below:

```
var askMom = function () {
    willIGetNewPhone // calling the promise
        .then(function (fulfilled1) {
            // yay, you got a new phone
            console.log(fulfilled);
        })
        .then(function (fulfilled2) {
            // yay, you got a new phone
            console.log(fulfilled2);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // ops, mom don't buy it
            console.log(error.message);
        });
}
```

It appears to me as if the code is saying - `nameOfObject.thenMehtod().thenMethod().catchMethod();`

How do I understand this? Does it mean it's normal in JavaSript to call methods of an object by using `nameOfObject.method1().method2().method3;`

Comment: You should read [How does basic object/function chaining work in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099628/how-does-basic-object-function-chaining-work-in-javascript)

Comment: `.` is not just restricted to functions. You can access any property using the `.` operator. Try this `a = {'a': 'a'}; a.a`

Answer (score 2):

When you call `.then()`, you're executing a function just like any other.  It then returns a promise that also can have `.then()` or `.catch()` called on it.

This is commonly referred to "chaining".

Answer (score 1):

This particular usage (`promise.then(...).then(...)`) looks similar but has nothing to do with your example `object.method1().method2().method3()`. In the former case (`promise.then()`) the result of each subsequent `.then()` is a new `Promise`. In the latter case, all methods normally return the same object, which makes it possible to do chaining, one example of it is `EventEmitter`:

```js
eventEmitter
  .on('event1', func1)
  .on('event2', func2);
```

Here, each `.on()` returns the same instance so this kind of method chaining is possible. To make this chaining, each method (`on` in the above example) should return the current instance (`this`).

Answer (score 1):

The basics is simple: `a.function()` takes an *input* and gives an *output*; the output could be any JavaScript *object*.

Now, what if `a.function()` returns something that is just like `a`? Now you can just continue forever. It's called *chaining* - a simple but powerful idea.

In the case of `promise`, `then` just *registers* a function that gets called with the `promise`'s resolved value. To make chaining possible, it also returns a `promise` that gets resolved with the function you supplied to `then`. If you aren't getting the idea, just read up further on `promises`, it will sink in.

Hope this small snippet using the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax can help you:

```
// getting the "resolver" to play around with
a = new Promise(_resolver_ => {resolver = _resolver_;});
// registering a "then"
b = a.then(result => {return result + 1;});
// resolving a
resolver(1);
```