# Returning 'resolve' function in Javascript Promise

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await, es6-promise

I have found a piece of code in [this blog](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/09/10/javascript-concurrency/) that works perfectly but makes a use of Promises that is hard to understand

```
export class Mutex {
  private mutex = Promise.resolve();

  lock(): PromiseLike<() => void> {
    let begin: (unlock: () => void) => void = unlock => {};

    this.mutex = this.mutex.then(() => {
      return new Promise(begin);
    });

    return new Promise(res => {
      begin = res;
    });
  }

  async dispatch(fn: (() => T) | (() => PromiseLike<T>)): Promise<T> {
    const unlock = await this.lock();
    try {
      return await Promise.resolve(fn());
    } finally {
      unlock();
    }
  }
}
```

- Is valid the expression `new Promise(res => { begin = res; })`? Promises usually involve calling `resolve` *on something*
- Why does `const unlock = await this.lock();` resolve to a function?

Comment: `res` is a bound method that can resolve (only that) Promise object. You can take *ownership* of the resolve function if you really want. See this answer of mine if you want to just play with resolve. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57106667/syntax-of-promises-in-javascript-is-confusing/57106943#57106943

Comment: `let begin: (unlock: () => void) => void = unlock => {};` doesn't make any sense, that arrow function is never called but immediately overwritten in the `new Promise` executor. It really should be just `lock(): PromiseLike<() => void> {
    return new Promise(begin => {
    this.mutex = this.mutex.then(() => {
      return new Promise(begin);
    });
    });
  }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it a valid expression? Promises usually involve calling resolve on something ...

Yes, it stores the resolve function in the global `begin` variable. Then when `new Promise(begin)` executes, it calls the `begin` function and thus resolves it.

> Why does const unlock = await this.lock(); resolve to a function?

Because `begin` gets called by `new Promise` with the resolve function of that new Promise (`begin(resolve, reject)`). As begin is a resolver itself, it'll resolve the returned Promise to the resolver function of the other promise.