# fadeIn and fadeOut "style" of an element in html, using jQuery or javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do something like the below code (by jQuery):

```
        $( "#ID_ELEMENT" ).style.backgroundColor="blue".fadeIn(100);
    setTimeout(function(){ $( "#ID_ELEMENT" ).style.backgroundColor="blue".fadeOut(100); }, 3000);
```

Thanks.

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Comment: Bad description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The challenge**

The code in your post appears to be an attempt to use method chaining (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475336/how-does-jquery-chaining-work) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099628/how-does-basic-object-function-chaining-work-in-javascript)) to:

1. Select the element with the `ID` attribute of `ID_ELEMENT`
2. Change that element's `background color` property to `blue`
3. Use the jQuery `fadeIn` effect on that updated element

And then:

1. Wait 3 seconds (3000ms)
2. Select the element with the `ID` attribute of `ID_ELEMENT`
3. Change that element's `background-color` property to `blue`
4. Use the jQuery `fadeOut` effect on that updated element

**The problems**

When using method chaining, each method returns an object that can be used by the next method in the chain. You have intermixed vanilla JavaScript and jQuery throughout your code:

- Not all functions in vanilla JavaScript return a value. It is not possible to use method chaining if a method does not return a value that can be used by the next method.
- The [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3) provides details about the functions, as well as information about the returned object (mostly jQuery collections).
  Because you have intermixed vanilla JavaScript and jQuery, your code will not work (see below).

**Breaking down *a* solution**

**(1)** The `$( "#ID_ELEMENT" )` selector in your code, creates a jQuery collection object for the element(s) with the `ID` of `ID_ELEMENT`. The creation of the jQuery collection object enables you to apply jQuery methods to the selected elements.

**(2)** In plain JavaScript, you can select a HTML element in the page (e.g. `document.getElementById( "ID_ELEMENT" )`).  This selection then provides access to methods and properties for that element.  For example, `.style.backgroundColor="blue"` is such a method, allowing an element's background colour to be updated to blue.

The methods available for a JavaScript DOM element are different to the methods available for a jQuery collection element, and the two elements are *not* interchangeable. More information about the available JavaScript methods can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). More information about jQuery methods can be found on the [jQuery website](https://api.jquery.com/).

JQuery includes the `.css()` method, which allows you to perform the same operation as `.style.backgroundColor`. Using the jQuery equivalent means that a jQuery collection object has been returned, ready to be used by the next method in the chain.

**(3)** Because the previous method returned a jQuery collection object, you can now use a further jQuery method on the returned object.

You can repeat the steps above to create a second method chain.  Note, the `background-color` property was already set to `blue` in the first stage of the code.  Unless you will be changing this property somewhere else, this operation may be redundant.

**Gives the result**

```js
$( "#ID_ELEMENT" ) // grab el in jQuery
     .css( "backgroundColor", "blue" ) // change  CSS background colour prop to blue
     .fadeIn(1000);  // fade element in
 
 // do something in 3s time...
 setTimeout(function(){ 
     $( "#ID_ELEMENT" )
         .css( "backgroundColor", "blue" ) // change CSS background to blue
         .fadeOut(1000);  // fade element out
 }, 3000);
```

```css
/* Optional - added sizing make demo more obvious */
div{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ID_ELEMENT"></div>
```

Comment: *N.B.* you can get a plain JavaScript DOM element from a jQuery collection object by referencing the position of that element in the jQuery collection.  If there is only a single element in the jQuery collection, the position will be 0.    For example:  jQuery( "#ID_ELEMENT" )[0]

Comment: It's good. but I want to remain element and don't effect fade in or fade out on the element but fade in and fade out must be just effected on "style" of that element. for example, if inner of the <div>hi</div> is "hi" it has to be always shown in the page and just the background of that div element has to change.

Comment: Thats a different question to the one originally asked.  Would suggest posting a fresh question, as there are a few ways to do this (and I can't add a snippet here to demonstrate). However, you can remove the 'fadeOut', replace 'blue' with [an 'RGBA' value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value). The 'A' stands for Alpha, and allows you to control the opacity of the colour. Create an 'RGBA(0, 0, 255, 0)' which is a transparent version of blue, for timeout.  Add a transition to the element, and when the solid blue changes to transparent blue, the background will fade out.