# Javascript - Create chainable functions without tainting everything

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chainable

I'm kind of newbie on JS, but I've done my research on the subject and found no exhaustive answer.

I'm using Angular JS for a project, and I have a service that expose some functions:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])

app.service('mySrv', function() {

    this.myFoo = function() {
        var anObject = {}
        //some code on the object...
        return anObject
    }

    this.myGoo = function() { // function(object) maybe?
        //some code on an object again
        return aNewObject
    }
}
```

Then in my controller I want to do something like JQuery does, **chaining the output of myFoo as the input of myGoo**

```
$scope.myObj = mySrv.myFoo(['some','params']).myGoo('another_one')
```

I've found that I could use the prototype properties in order to add chainability, as stated here [How to make chainable function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730334/how-to-make-chainable-function-in-javascript)
But the same answer says that it should not be done on Objects, which will be my case...

Last but not least, ther is this other method [JavaScript Object Method Chaining: useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603499/javascript-object-method-chaining-useful/15797662#15797662)
which, frankly, I didn't understand...

Can someone clear all this fog from my mind?

---

**EDIT:**
Using and mixing the great examples from @plalx and @Connor, I've managed to get this snippet working, and as you can see, is missing the "chainable part" of @plalx example.

What the hell that part exactly does?

```
var o = {
    setTest: function (test) {
        this.test = test;
        return this
    },
    getTest: function () {
        this.test = this.test.toUpperCase()
        return this
    },
    splitMe: function() {
        return this.test.split('')
    }
};

console.log( o.setTest('hello').getTest().splitMe() )
```

Comment: If a function returns an object, and that object has properties (either directly or via its prototype chain) whose values are functions, then you've got "chaining".  The *semantics* of the chaining depend on what kinds of objects are involved.

Comment: Do you want the **result** of `myFoo(someParams)` to be passed as additionnal arguments to `myGoo` when doing `myFoor(someParams).myGoo()` or you simply want all functions to return the context object (like in jQuery)? That are two different concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example on how you could make any object methods chainable dynamically.

Calling `chainable(obj)` will internally create a new object that exposes the same API as `obj`, however every function will now return that new object which in turns allow chaining. If you want to call a function and get the raw result of that function, you can call `endChain()`.

The following implementation is not very efficient since it has to loop over all members of `obj`. **A better approach would be to make your methods chainable by returning the current instance (`this`) from the functions you want to be chainable.**

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VxgyA/)

```
var chainable = (function () {

    function wrapFn(fn, obj) {
        return function () {
            var result = this._result = fn.apply(obj, arguments);

            return this;
        };
    }

    function Chainable(obj) {
        var k, v;

        for (k in obj) {
            if (typeof (v = obj[k]) !== 'function') continue;

            this[k] = wrapFn(obj[k], obj);
        }
    }

    Chainable.prototype.endChain = function () {
        return this._result;
    };

    return function (obj) {
        return new Chainable(obj);
    };

})();

var o = {
    setTest: function (test) {
        this.test = test;
    },
    getTest: function () {
        return this.test;
    }
};

console.log(chainable(o).setTest('test').getTest().endChain());
```

Here's a different implementation that doesn't require to iterate over the object members. However it's less appealing syntaxically and I am not sure that it's more efficient since it has to `slice` arguments.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VxgyA/1/)**

```
var chainable = (function (slice) {
    var Chainable = {
        init: function (obj) {
            this._obj = obj;

            return this;
        },

        chain: function (fn) {
            var obj = this._obj;

            this._result = obj[fn].apply(obj, slice.call(arguments, 1));

            return this;
        },

        end: function () {
            return this._result;
        }
    };

    return function (obj) {
        return Object.create(Chainable).init(obj);
    };
})(Array.prototype.slice);

var o = {
    setTest: function (test) {
        this.test = test;
    },
    getTest: function () {
        return this.test;
    }
};

console.log(chainable(o).chain('setTest', 'test').chain('getTest').end());
```

EDIT:

> Using and mixing the great examples from @plalx and @Connor, I've
>   managed to get this snippet working, and as you can see, is missing
>   the "chainable part" of @plalx example.

You do not need something like `chainable` if your code **is already written in a way it can be chained (e.g. already returning `this` from some functions)**. I should have made it more clear. I just wrote the `chainable` implementation as an example on how chaining works.

However, with `chainable` you can make **any** object chainable, even if none of their functions explicitely return `this`. It could be useful if you want to use chaining with objects that aren't supporting it through their API.

E.g.

```
var o = {
    fn1: function () { console.log('fn1'); },
    fn2: function () { console.log('fn2'); }
};

//chainable(o).fn1().fn2(); //other implementation

chainable(o).chain('fn1').chain('fn2');
```

**Here's a [performance test](http://jsperf.com/dynamic-chain) that shows making your object dynamically chainable has a huge negative performance impact. For that reason I wouldn't recommend using that experimental approach.**

Comment: Great, thanks.
I've edited my question based on your answer... 
Could you check it out when you have a minute?

Thx!

Comment: Great, got it now.
My code is still not working in the Angular environment, but I'm sure it's a scope related problem.
I'll sort it out soon enough.

Thanks!

Comment: oops, Stackoverflow newbie here :P
Done, just now

Cya!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use `return this;` like so.

```
app.service('mySrv', function() {

    this.myFoo = function() {
        var anObject = {}
        //some code on the object...
        return this;
    }

    this.myGoo = function() { // function(object) maybe?
        //some code on an object again
        return this;
    }
}
```

You shouldn't be returning anything else if it's chain-able because you won't be able to use it anyway. Just like everything in jQuery there are some like `offset();` that are not chainable.